# JOptionPane not printing method for-loop variable

Tags: java, for-loop, joptionpane

I have this method called "cambiar", i am receiving data from an array called "articulos", then i put that data in my "datos" variable.
But the output is just printing something like:

Select which article you would like to change
xx (I use this xx word as a reference)

My code is not printing "datos" variable, and i dont know why.

```
public ArrayList<Item> cambiar() {
        
    String datos = "\n";
    int cantidad;
    String nombre;
    for (int i = 0; i < articulos.size(); i++) {
        cantidad = articulos.get(i).getCantidad();
        nombre = articulos.get(i).getP().getNombre();
        datos = "Articulo: " + nombre + ", Cantidad:" + cantidad + "\n";
    }
    int art = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select which article you would like to change\n"+ datos+"xx"));
    articulos.get(art);
    articulos.get(art).getCantidad();
    int cuan = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many would you like buy?"));
    articulos.get(art).setCantidad(cuan);
    return articulos;
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve], people can only guess what your problem is - as you can see by the answers to your question. Why not just add the following line to method `cambiar` immediately before the `for` loop: `System.out.println(articulos.size());` You know, it's called debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I see some lines that might be the issue:

1. the line `articulos.get(art);` don't doing anything, so I recommend to remove it.
2. in the line  `datos = "Articulo: " + nombre + ", Cantidad:" + cantidad + "\n";` there are 2 problems.
   The first is I suspose tou want to display all exsts article, so tou need to replace the `=` by `+=` to add all your strings to one.
   The second is you use in `\n` in `JOptionPane`, and this won't work.
   In `JOptionPane`, you can style your message by using HTML only, and not java String syntax.
   You can do that by add `"<html>"` before your message (and for more reabable code, `"</html>"`after this), in addition to replace all `"\n"` in `"</br>"`.
   For example:

```
public ArrayList<Item> cambiar() {
        
    String datos = "<br/>";
    int cantidad;
    String nombre;
    for (int i = 0; i < articulos.size(); i++) {
        cantidad = articulos.get(i).getCantidad();
        nombre = articulos.get(i).getP().getNombre();
        datos += "Articulo: " + nombre + ", Cantidad:" + cantidad + "<br/>";
    }
    int art = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"<html>Select which article you would like to change<br/>"+ datos+"xx</html>"));
    articulos.get(art);
    articulos.get(art).getCantidad();
    int cuan = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many would you like buy?"));
    articulos.get(art).setCantidad(cuan);
    return articulos;
}
```

Comment: _The second is you use in `\n` in `JOptionPane`, and this won't work_ This is not correct.

Comment: _replace all "\n" in "</br>"_ The HTML tag should be `<br/>` or `<br>`

Comment: </html> after help to more readable code, by </br> or <br/>, you correct, I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your articulos list is empty and the for loop is not event starting.

I'm not sure what are you trying to do with this method/messages, even if you manage to fix your 'articulos' list, your 'datos' variable will get only the last element of your list. Either combine your data by using the += compound assigment opperator or move the rest code into the for loop (and not use the +=) in order to pop up your dialogs on each element.